# Is there a gcc compiler under ARM?

Tags: gcc, arm

I know that if I want to compile a program for an ARM device I need a special version of gcc that runs under x86 and compiles for ARM (cross compiling) is there a way to compile for ARM under ARM?

Comment: Yes, I'm know this exists, but what OS are you running that would run an ARM compile natively, out of curiousity?

Comment: @Michael Dorgan for the sake of argument lets say it's just a Linux kernel and a busybox multicall binary   ,and for the compiler I use linaro arm gcc compiler it runs under x86 and compile for arm android or Linux

Comment: Then, if you cannot find your flavor, you download the source of the compiler you want and build it.  I could see one using, on an x86 box to start,  an x86 cross compiler to compile the ARM version of the compiler for your local ARM based system.  Then you can use the native version going forward on your system.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+download has the latest source you could possibly use for this adventure :)

Comment: I will give it a try ,I don't know if it's going to work or not ,but still worth a try

Comment: I'll make this an answer then fo others to read.  Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are happy to compile from source, any recent version of GCC can be built natively on an ARM device, targeting that ARM device. The dependencies to compile GCC and the size of the code base might give you some difficulties, but I regularly build the up-to-date GCC development branch on my Raspberry Pi 2.

Follow the instructions at: https://gcc.gnu.org/install/ to get the prerequisites you need, and when configuring the compiler use something like:

```
  --with-cpu=cortex-a15 --with-float=hard --with-fpu=neon --with-mode=thumb
```

Modifying the `--with-cpu` and `--with-fpu` options as required for your system.

If you are looking for prebuilt binaries, most distributions (and certainly Debian and Ubuntu) which run on ARM will provide you with a package you can install, just like your x86 systems.

Comment: thanks for the answer and the reference link ,I will let you all know if it worked ,the size of the required tools might be a problem but I can always extend the size of storage on my box

Answer (score 1):

Consider downloading the source code for the compiler of your choice. [Here](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+download) is a location that contains the source you could attempt to use.

I could see one using, on an x86 box to start, an x86 cross compiler to compile the ARM version of the compiler for your local ARM based system. Then you can use the native version going forward on your system.

Answer (score 1):

yes there are cross compilers and yes there are native compilers.  You can for example buy a raspberry pi and install one of the canned distros and that gives you a native compiler, or you can for example use qemu and run an arm distro built for one of the many systems supported by qemu simulations (and run a native compiler on that)...or just cross compile.

Answer (score 0):

Recent Debian for Raspberry Pi 2 came with gcc 4.6. For more advanced features, such as for NEON, you can install gcc 4.8, or later. Example compile commands for different FPU options are:

```
 gcc 4.6
 gcc  linpack.c cpuidc.c -lm -lrt -O3 -march=armv6 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp -o linpackPiA6
 gcc 4.8
  gcc  linpack.c cpuidc.c -lm -lrt -O3 -mcpu=cortex-a7 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -o linpackPiA7
```

Comment: for the compiling process ,I know how to do it I compile for arm devices all the time and for different processors a-7 a-9 a-15 I do that in the make file since it's a big project ,but thanks it might help someone else looking for answers :D